# Angular 5 - implement Data Service to read JSON from MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to implement a data service to read json data from mongoDB. I was able to implement the function directly in the ngOnInit() of my component, but when I tried to implement a separate data service, I just can't get the json data into my component.

**intro-animation.component.ts**:

```
export class IntroAnimationComponent implements OnInit {
  keywords: string[];
  ...
}

constructor(
  private _http: HttpClient) {
  ...
}

ngOnInit() {
  this._http.get('./api/keywords').subscribe(res => {
    this.keywords = res['data'];
  });
}
```

So this works fine, but now I would prefer to create a data service class to use it on other components as well to access different tables in my database. 
This is what I tried so far, without success:

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  results: string[];

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
    getKeywords(): string[] {
      this.getKeywordsObservable().subscribe(res => {
      this.results = res['data'];
    });
    return this.results;
  }

  getKeywordsObservable(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("./api/keywords")
  }
}
```

I registered the service in my app.module, but I just don't know how to get the data from the service into my component.

**intro-animation.component.html**

```
<div class="keywords-container" *ngFor="let keyword of keywords">
  <div class="keyword" [ngStyle]="setKeywordFontParams()">
    {{ keyword.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**mongoDB json data**

```
{
"status": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "5a60740d94d06e102e8c2475",
        "name": "Passion"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a60745be4b93b2c36f6a891",
        "name": "Grandeur"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a607461e4b93b2c36f6a892",
        "name": "Prestige"
    }
],
"message": null
}
```

I am still new to Angular and hope you could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataService `getKeywords()` method further calls `http.get` which is **`async`**.
So when you do `return this.results;` It is actually still `undefined` so you get nothing.

So better way will be to simply return observable from **data.service.ts** *Like:*

```
 getKeywordsObservable(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("./api/keywords")
  }
```

and, subscribe inside the **intro-animation.component**. *Like* :

```
ngOnInit() {
      this._dataService.getKeywordsObservable().subscribe(res => {
        this.keywords = res['data'];
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it worked! I didn't really know enough about Promises and Observables to understand the process behind it. I did dive into those subjects more now and it's clearer now :)

Answer (score 0):

**intro-animation.component.ts:**

```
import {DataService} from "<location of service>" 

    export class IntroAnimationComponent implements OnInit {
      keywords: string[];

    constructor(
      private _service: DataService) {
      ...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this._service.getKeywords().subscribe(res => {
        this.keywords = res;
      });
    }
```

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }


  getKeywords(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("./api/keywords")
  }
}
```

Hope this will helps

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  public getKeywords(): any {
    return this._http.get('./api/keywords').map(res => {
      return res['data'];
    });
  }

}
```

Now in the component you could inject this service and call it `dataService.getKeywords()`